# Smooth $S^1$-bundle over complex projective line

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

What are all the smooth $S^1$-bundles over $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$? i.e. What are all smooth manifolds so that $S^1\to X \to \mathbb
{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ is a smooth fiber bundle?

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your thought about the question?

Comment: The trivial bundle is there. However, if $CP^1$ is sitting inside some complex manifold of complex dimension 2. Then there can be self-intersection of $CP^1$ which may affect the $S^1$-bundle (which can constructed from boundary of a tubular nbd). I am worried about how such self-intersection affects these bundles.

Comment: Are you at all familiar with theory of fiber bundles beyond the definition? For instance, do you know what the Euler class of a circle bundle is?

Comment: I don't know. In fact it would be helpful if you can suggest some approach to solve the above question.